# How do I transfer an instance of a type from a macro to the compiled program?

Tags: rust

I have a macro that processes tokens into some nested structs.

I use these structs are a kind of "intermediate representation", that are then converted into output tokens by the macro.

I want to use these "intermediate representation" types at runtime as well though.

So if I have an instance of a Rust struct in a macro, how do I output that into the end program?

I could share the type between the macro crate and the output program crate, but to get the instance data would I have to do something like serialize to a JSON string, embed into the end program, and then parse the JSON string at runtime?

Thanks.

Simple example of a macro:

```rust
// This type will be used in both the macro and the program.
pub struct X {
    a: String,
    b: String
}

fn impl_x(ast: &syn::DeriveInput) -> TokenStream {
    let x: X = ast.into();


    let gen = quote! {
        fn get_x() -> X {
            // How to transfer instance `x` to the output TokenStream?
            
        }
    };

    gen.into()
}
```

Note: I am looking for a general way to do this that works with large nested structs.

Comment: Could you give an example of the input that is to be tokenized?

Comment: Something like this maybe: https://crates.io/crates/uneval

Comment: maybe you can add a 3rd crate to define all the common structs and have it imported in both and re-exported in the main crate

Comment: I think I can share the types that way, but what’s the best way to serialise the actual insurance? I am thinking of just embedding the JSON string then parsing it at runtime. Is there something that would take an instance and output the Rust source code to build that instance?